# Storing Objects in a List in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, object, variables

If an object exists with variable .X

```
randomData.X
```

is the created object. If multiple objects are stored in a list and can be accessed via

```
randomList[3].X
```

Is there a way to pull all values of X from the list without looping through every object in the list as below:

```
for x i range(0,10)
randomList[x].X
```

Comment: No. There isn't. You'll have to loop one way or anther, `list` object do no support vectorized attribute access, or any vectorized operations. Although in this case (in most cases), you should just loop over the list directly: `for item in randomList: item.X`

Comment: Are you asking if you can pull fewer than the whole `list`s worth of `X`s, or how to pull the `X`s efficiently?

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for a list comprehension.

```
[obj.X for obj in randomList]
```

This produces a list with all properties X of every object in your list of objects.

Keep in mind that you can't get away from looping over the list. This is just syntactic sugar for the same loop as before.

Comment: I suspect this is what the OP is after, but probably worth mentioning that it *still* loops over every item — it's just a more succinct way of doing it.

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: Thanks very much. Maybe storing lots of data in this object format is not the most efficient as I will need to do lots of searches within the data.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you're looking for maximum efficiency on larger `list`s, an alternative to the `list` comprehension in this case is using `map` + [`operator.attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter). You can either loop over the `map` directly:

```
from operator import attrgetter

for X in map(attrgetter('X'), randomList):
```

which involves no temporary `list` (`map` lazily pulls items on demand in Python 3), or if you really need the `list`, just wrap in the `list` constructor or use `list` unpacking to run it out eagerly:

```
Xs = list(map(attrgetter('X'), randomList))
# or
Xs = [*map(attrgetter('X'), randomList)]
```

For small input `list`s, this will be slower than the `list` comprehension (it has a slightly higher setup overhead), but for medium to large inputs, it will be faster (the per-item overhead is slightly lower, as it involves no per-item bytecode execution).

To be clear, it's still going to have to loop over the `list`. There is no magic way to get the attributes of every item in a `list` without looping over it; you could go to extreme lengths to make views of the `list` that seamlessly read the attribute from the underlying `list`, but if you accessed every element of that view it would be equivalent to the loop in work required.